# Instances of class A as class attributes of A in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

Are there Python versions that allow defining your class like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

and then adding `class attributes`, such as `BAR_1, BAR_2`, etc.:

```
class Foo:
    BAR_1 = ...
    BAR_2 = ...

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

which are actually "special cases of `Foo`", such as:

```
class Foo:
    BAR_1 = Foo(4, 9, 16)
    BAR_2 = Foo(2, 3, 5)

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

so that, in my code, I can either make my own `Foos` or get common, predefined `Foos` by working directly with `Foo.BAR_1` and `Foo.BAR_2`?

The code above obviously does not work, otherwise I would not post the question (`Foo` is an unresolved reference when defining `BAR_1` and `BAR_2`). I found a trick on SO how to sort-of achieve this -> defining a custom `ClassProperty` class:

```
class ClassProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return self.f(owner)
```

which then allows me to define `Foo` as

```
class Foo:
    @ClassProperty
    def BAR_1(cls):
        return Foo(4, 9, 16)

    @ClassProperty
    def BAR_2(cls):
        return Foo(2, 3, 5)

    ...
```

and that works, but the issue is that `Foo.__init__` is called everytime whenever `Foo.BAR_1` or `Foo.BAR_2` is retrieved, which can be useful in certain situations (precisely those where you always want separate instances), but in the special case where `Foo` is simply a messenger class which is coincidentally hard to load (like a result of a computation for example), this solution is unfeasible. I'd like for the constructor of `Foo` to be called exactly once for `BAR_1`, exactly once for `BAR_2` (ideally lazily, during the first retrieval, that would be fantastic), and after that it would only return the created instances. So, is there a way to do this?

I use `Python 3.8.6`.

Answer (score 0):

During the time I composed the question body, I figured out I can just define `Foo` like this:

```
class Foo:
    @ClassProperty
    def BAR_1(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_Foo__BAR_1'):
            cls.__BAR_1 = Foo(4, 9, 16)
        return cls.__BAR_1

    @ClassProperty
    def BAR_2(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_Foo__BAR_2'):
            cls.__BAR_2 = Foo(2, 3, 5)
        return cls.__BAR_2
```

Now, I can call `Foo.BAR_X` for retrieval of a defined `Foo.__BAR_X` which is actually an instance of `Foo`, which is always created only once.